# Is there a html validator that can point to a mismatches like this?

Tags: html, validation

Occasionally press a hyphen so the first symbol in a html file (php generated) was not a tag start, but a general symbol. Firefox didn't care about it (it was a joomla source), but IE acted like I did something more dangerous: not centered table, misaligned text, looked like a complete mess. I know that there are always things like this, but I wasted a couple of hours to figure out what was going on. Is there a html validator that can point to things like this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example? Not sure what symbol you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Total Validator](http://totalvalidator.com/tool/index.html) would flag it with **This element is not recognised**.

Comment: Indeed. It's a great companion. :)

Answer (score 1):

Most validators will do that.

Try the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/). I tried a valid file with a symbol at the start and it flagged it.